# PHPmyAdmin 4.8.0 - apache2 behind nginx proxy - session_cookie error on login

Tags: php, nginx, cookies, phpmyadmin

I updated PHPmyAdmin to the new release 4.8.0 under ubuntu 17.10. I have nginx 1.12.1 as proxy in front of apache 2.4.33. Now when i try to login i get the following error-message:

`Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin.`

Previously to that upgrade everything worked fine. Login over apache-port (without nginx) works also. Here is my nginx-config:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name phpmyadmin.localhost;

    index index.php index.nginx-debian.html index.html index.htm;

    location / {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_cache_valid 3s;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_PHPSESSID;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_PHPSESSID;
        proxy_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpmyadmin$uri$is_args$args;       

    }

    location /phpmyadmin/ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_cache_valid 3s;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_PHPSESSID;
        proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_PHPSESSID;
        proxy_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$uri$is_args$args;      

    }

}
```

Anybody got some idea whats going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this issue.

For this exact configuration this issue is solved with:
`proxy_cookie_path /phpmyadmin/ /;` in one of the location blocks.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_path

using : `nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)`